# how to implement 2-way SSL certificate for WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl, x509certificate

I am a newbie to WCF so trying to figure out how to implement 2way ssl certficate authentication for WCF service i need to host. The consumer of the service would provide us with there certificate and we are supposed to provide them with ours.

The part i don't understand and would appreciate help is how to do we go about it in the way of either
1. articles pointing out the steps
or 
2. Code samples.

Thanks.

Comment: AT this point any articles which can help accomplish this (not necessary step by step) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following web pages provide a fairly comprehensive overview of a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service and client secured using mutual certificate authentication.  The code and configuration in the articles were helpful when our team first tackled WCF services with mutual x509 certificate authentication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF

Regards,