# WCF authentication using ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: c#, wcf

It's been a week already and I'm still not fully comfortable with implementing ASP.NET Membership Provider with WCF. I'm wondering:

1. We already have a website which is running under HTTPS protocol. We are working on a new application which will have a WCF service and is going to replace our old application (with HTTPS). Now my question is, since we already have a secured website, do I have to get another certificate just for the WCF service?
2. If yes, then do I have to get certificates for clients as well? (As I was looking on the web, most of the answers I found were "yes".)
3. If no, can I use the existing certificate to authenticate my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have 1 SSL Certificate per domain unless you purchase a wildcard certificate. So, if your current SSL Certificate is for subdomain.mydomain.com and you want to host the WCF service at anothersubdomain.mydomain.com (or even www.anotherdomain.com), then you'll need another certificate. If this is something that would happen fairly frequently, then I'd suggest you purchase a *.mydomain.com SSL certificate.

Another option would be to host the WCF service under the current subdomain with a URL like subdomain.mydomain.com\myservice\service.svc.

I can't answer your second question but I doubt you are using client side certificates.

Here's a link to a [Beginner's guide on SSL Certificates](https://www.symantec.com/pages.jsp?id=ssl-certificates-guide).

Comment: Hi Lee to be more precise. Let's say Our application is hosting on https://appname.xxx.yyy.cc.mm. Now My service URL will be like this https://appname.xxx.yyy.cc.mm/myservice.svc. We already have certificate for xxx.yyy.cc.mm As per your suggestion I think I don't have to go with other certificate. please confirm. And thanks for your help

Comment: appname.xxx.yyy.cc.mm is not the same as xxx.yyy.cc.mm. If your certificate is for xxx.yyy.cc.mm you'll want to either host the service as xxx.yyy.cc.mm\servicename\service.svc or you'll need to purchase a new certificate appname.xxx.yyy.cc.mm (or alternatively purchase a wildcard certificate *.xxx.yyy.cc.mm which is more expensive but cost effective if you'll have many different subdomain).

Comment: You should contact the company you purchased the SSL Certificate from. They will help you figure out what you need. It appears you can add Subject Alternative Names (SAN) to the certificate. Read this too...http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/what-certificates-are-needed-for-multi-level-subdomains

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 2nd question, you only need client certificates if you want your WCF service to support mutual (2-way) SSL authentication, in which both the server and client sides are authenticated by their respective certificates.

Refer to this question for further information on mutual ssl and wcf.

[how to implement 2-way SSL certificate for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056351/how-to-implement-2-way-ssl-certificate-for-wcf)